# Mysql Replication Restore

Tags: mysql, replication

How can I start one slave and tell him to stop updating in one date and time?

Like "update slave until Friday 9:00"?

Is possible?

Thanks in advance?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If you want replication to stop at that point, you'll have to issue a command to stop it at that time.

Comment: Thanks! and if I create one new slave, how can I stop update in one old position, like last friday?